# QGIS 2.2 Atlas - Blank Export

Tags: qgis, atlas

I've got a map laid out how I want it in QGIS 2.2, using the "Atlas Generation" feature. When I preview the atlas, all 7 pages look proper and seem to work fine. However, I cannot export them to any format as it always results in blank pages (the proper number though, so it appears to be 'iterating' properly).

If it matters, it's set to print as raster as I have some transparency.  Thoughts on what is wrong?

Comment: Might be worth a bug report. It would be great if you can attach the zipped project file + data to reproduce to the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was caused by some 'corrupt' spatial data. I cleaned up one of the files, and things all seem to work properly now.